# Send function to call() as argument

Tags: javascript, this, call, global-object

here in this example

```js
function a() { console.log(this.x); }

var x = 10;
a.x = 20;

a.call(a);
```

The result is `20`

Why does this happen?

I know in call method we can send object but here send a function? can we do that? and why does a.x work?

Answer (score 2):

The call() method can be used to invoke a function with a specific `this` value, which can be an object or any other value.

In this example, `a.x` works because functions in JavaScript are also objects and can have properties added to them. So, `a.x` adds a property `x` to the function `a`.